# How to create line icon comprises paths in sketch?

Tags: icon, path, sketch-app

Hi！ It's my first post.

I am totally newbie in sketch, also in design.

Because I want to use the "Shared style" function which can let me change all icons' style quickly (just like this tutorial [Sketch 3 Tutorial Shared Styles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpoFMytRY6w). One click then you can change all icons' colour.
So I tried to mimic a line icon as below image. But my result looks strange. 
Please see the image.
[image: Why my result so strange?]

My question is :
How to turn icon become a lot of piece? (I tried flatten, it didn't work.)
Actually, I even don't know if I ask right question.
Please someone tell me how to make line icon in sketch in correct way!

@hack_nug Mr.hack_nug:
please see below image.

All ovals made by borders,and I also union them.

But my dots are just "line" circles.

I don't know how to union border circle and remain dots at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're drawing twice every shape (one slightly smaller than the other) and subtracting them to get the line shape. What you should be doing instead is drawing the shape once, removing the filling color and giving it an border color and size (you'll probably want to center it).

Do this for all three ovals, its respective dots and the outer circle. Once you're done use the `Union` button to turn them into a single shape without losing the hability to modify each of its parts (non-destructive transformations are your new best friends).

Don't worry about the strange twisted things you mention. That's just showing you the icon it's made of differents shapes or paths. Also don't worry about your icon not having all those pieces you see in your sample icon. That's because that icon hasn't been correctly drawn or exported.

Just remember that if you want to make line icons, you should *only* use the border color. That will let you change it's color, position and thickness whenever you want or need (that's why you'll use shared styles, so all of them use the same border options).

Comment: Mr. hack_nug:
Thank you for answer me!
I have tried the way you taught me, but result is not perfect. 
My dots become line circles...
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Vin_Lin you could have two different style with the same border options (one with a fill color and one without it). Then apply your line style to every element except those you need to be filled. Just make sure both style share the same border options.

Comment: Here's a Sketch document I just made to show you what I meant by that. You can select both squares, modify only their border options and sync the styles to have Sketch apply them to the rest of the elements using them. https://we.tl/LLQyJHwMxR

Comment: Mr. hack_nug: Thank you for the example! So if I want to use shared style in this case, I have to use "2" shared styles, one is shared "border" and the other is shared "border" and "fill". hmm, I did use this way before I ask question.But I want to use just one shared style to change all icons in one time. So it still didn't solve my problem. Link is how I use 1 shared style to change all icons' style. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-c0ytJJUceIYzNnR0hOdGNENzA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Vin_Lin I don't think you can do it unless the width and height of the small circles is the same size as the border thickness if this one's aligned to the center.